# Please suggest required linq for following query

Tags: c#, linq

Im getting output as `list` object `lstResourceList`

```
  HID   NAME   DID  APID  PID   
    3   Aban    1   1   1
    4   Abbas   2   8   5
    4   Abbas   2   5   5
    5   SAAD    4   1   1
    6   GAURAV  4   5   5
    8   Radhesh 2   -1  -1
    1   Abaan   1   8   -1
```

from these records i want first select those record whose HID count > 1 .
say i get

```
HID  NAME DID APID  PID   
 4  Abbas   2   8   5
 4  Abbas   2   5   5
```

now from thse record i want select record having APID not equal to 8.
that is =>

```
 HID NAME  DID  APID   PID   
  4 Abbas   2   5      5
```

Now i want to remove this record from my output list .that is final output shoul be

```
 HID   NAME    DID  APID PID   
    3   Aban    1   1   1
    4   Abbas   2   8   5
    5   SAAD    4   1   1
    6   GAURAV  4   5   5
    8   Radhesh 2   -1  -1
    1   Abaan   1   8   -1
```

Any suggestion for linq operation???

Comment: You should try atleast something?

Comment: use as `list.select(a=>a.HID>1 && a.APID!=8).ToList();`

Comment: i tried in oracle using query  as `select  HRESOURCE_ID ,PATTERN_ID 
from T_FP_EMPLOYEE_PATTERN_MAPPING
where HRESOURCE_ID in(select HRESOURCE_ID
         from T_FP_EMPLOYEE_PATTERN_MAPPING
         group by HRESOURCE_ID  having count(*)>1);` to fetch such clumn but in linq i am facing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, group your items on `HID` to find the elements that share a `HID`. Once filtered, you can then filter each group by its own on `APID`. After that, flatten the result to get the items you want to remove in a single list.

Should be something like this:

```
var toRemove = lstResourceList.GroupBy(x => x.HID)
                              .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                              .SelectMany(grp => grp.Where(x => x.APID != 8))
                              .ToList();

foreach(var item in toRemove)
    lstResourceList.Remove(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
lstResourceList = lstResourceList.Where(x => x.HID>1 && x.APID != 8).ToList();
```

**EDIT: My answer is wrong. I misunderstood the question. See comments below**

Comment: This will not lead to the desired result.

Comment: @DominicKexel... why?

Comment: It will filter out the items `4   Abbas   2   8   5` and `1   Abaan   1   8   -1`, which should stay. The item `4 Abbas   2   5      5` should be removed, because there are multiple items with `HID = 4`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave my previous answer. Understood the question now.